# SharePoint 2010 events: "SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: Initialization"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, events

I'm running a SharePoint 2010 environment. Upon checking my eventviewer I noticed I'm regularly receiving the following events:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: SharePoint Foundation
Event ID: 8312
Level: Information
OpCode: Info
Task Category: Topology

SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: Initialization
Process Name: OWSTIMER
Process ID: 16520
AppDomain Name: DefaultDomain
AppDomain ID: 1
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:****#authority=urn:uuid:****&authority=https://****:**/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:0
Endpoint List:
http://****:**/****/ProfileService.svc
```

Followed by the event:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: SharePoint Foundation
Event ID: 8312
Level: Information
OpCode: Info
Task Category: Topology

SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: Initialization
Process Name: OWSTIMER
Process ID: 16520
AppDomain Name: DefaultDomain
AppDomain ID: 1
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:****#authority=urn:uuid:****&authority=https://****:**/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:0
Endpoint List:
http://****:**/****/MetadataWebService.svc
```

Followed by the event:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: SharePoint Foundation
Event ID: 8312
Level: Information
OpCode: Info
Task Category: Topology

SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: Initialization
Process Name: OWSTIMER
Process ID: 16520
AppDomain Name: DefaultDomain
AppDomain ID: 1
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:****#authority=urn:uuid:****&authority=https://****:**/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:0
Endpoint List:
http://****:**/****/WebAnalyticsService.svc
```

Can anyone shed light on these events? What is causing them and is it possible or necessary to solve them?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting the same issue in our SP Ent 2010 3 tier farm. Is it an issue? For me It seems to be as the page loads very slowly when these topology messages show up in the developer dashboard. The services mentioned are profile services, managed metadata, and search service. Event 8312 only, not 8313 which signals an endpoint failure.. .nothing in the uls or event viewer either.

Comment: Hello Maria, I'm sorry, but I never managed to resolve it. The farm that had this event ended up being reinstalled by a consulting firm for other reasons than this event.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Harlan describes a similar issue (http://www.ericharlan.com/Moss_SharePoint_2007_Blog/web-services-round-robin-service-load-balancer-event-a216.html). It might be related to your farm topology and having search service running without actually having the proper services (see Services on Server) started. In that case it would be good to stop the "QSearch Query and Site Settings Service" so it doesn't server queries. Try running the following PowerShell commands to stop it

```
$qs = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance -local
Stop-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $qs
```

Comment: Thank you for the relevant link! Let me check if there is an ULS log entry corresponding with Harlan's blog. I will post my findings.

Comment: There is not a corresponding error in my ULS log. My SharePoint environment consist of only 1 server. I don't think it would be a good idea for me to stop the instance of the search manager service (Stop-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance). I think the correct services are running on the server. "Search Query and Site Settings Service" and "SharePoint Server Search" are up and running.